# Error in my project. I am creating sign up page and have an error with my code

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting error in my project. I am trying to create sign up page. And i am almost done with this page but i am getting error in this code. Whats wrong with this code? i am using xcode 8 and swift 3 . But when i change the "where" with this "," so its working but i still get error when i run the app.

```
 @IBAction func RegisterDidTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text where !email.isEmpty, let password = passwordTextField.text where !password.isEmpty, let username = usernameTextField.text where !username.isEmpty else {
        return
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain the exact error message that you get. Also, explain in your question when you get the error. For example, you might get the error when you compile the code or you might get the error when you run the code. Finally, you code looks incomplete. I count two opening curly braces, but no closing curly braces. If this is your complete code, then it's clear that you'll get a syntax error when you attempt to compile this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using guard to unwrap several optionals (which is a great way to do it), you need to put those before your conditional checks, so in this case you'd want to say: `guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, (etc.)` and then put the checks for empty at the end.

Comment: You can use isEmpty on Swift strings.